# Markers not showing in map when geocoding address

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm working with Google Maps API for a project and I'm stuck with this Geociding thing for days...

I need to use geocoding to go in reverse and get the lat and lng from a given address, so I need these functions to create the location points.

```
var glocations = [];
var locations = [];
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: ''});
var geocoder;
var map;

function initMap() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(40.6976637,-74.1197637);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: center,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        fullscreenControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TRAFFIC,
        styles: []

    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    locations = [
    ['0', '','Title', codeAddressLat('brooklyn', '0'), codeAddressLng('brooklyn', '0'), 'category-1', 'https://sat.ptvtelecom.net/img/red.png'],//this doesn't work
    ['1', '', 'Title', 40.6976637,-74.1197637, 'category-2', 'https://sat.ptvtelecom.net/img/green.png']//this works
    ];

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var url = locations[i][6];
        addMarker(locations[i], url);
    }
}


function addMarker(marker, url) {
    var category = marker[5];
    var title = marker[1];
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[3], marker[4]);
    var content = marker[2];
    var icon = {
        url: url,
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32)
    };
    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: title,
        icon: icon,
        position: pos,
        category: category,
        map: map
    });
    glocations.push(marker1);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function (marker1, content) {
        return function () {
            infoWindow.setContent(content);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker1);
            map.panTo(this.getPosition());
            map.setZoom(20);
        }
    })(marker1, content));
}


function codeAddressLat(address, index) {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        var latLng = {lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat (), lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng ()};
        var lat = latLng.lat;
        if (status == 'OK') {
            locations[index][3] = lat;//this will change the lat value, but it won't show on map
            //return lat;//this will return undefined lat
        }
    });
}


function codeAddressLng(address, index) {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        var latLng = {lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat (), lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng ()};
        var lng = latLng.lng;
        if (status == 'OK') {
            locations[index][4] = lng;//this will change the lng value, but it won't show on map
            //return lng;//this will return undefined lng
        }
    });
}


initMap();
```

Okay, so I have three outputs here:

1. If I write down the lat and long values directly, the location will get the float values and the marker show in the map.
2. If I manipulate the locations array, the location will get float values and the marker won't show in the map.
3. If the functions return the values, the location will get undefined values and the marker won't show in the map.

You can see what the output looks like in the following screenshot(just url, I can't post images):

sat.ptvtelecom.net/img/result.png

Any help would be so much appreciate.

Comment: You can't do it that way. The Geocoder is an **asynchronous request** which means that it takes a bit of time to get results back from it (also you should know that there are [usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing#other-usage-limits) and billing). At the time you loop through `locations` to create the markers, the line which calls the Geocoder is most likely still empty. Also what is the point having separate functions to geocode latitude and longitude? You should check some basic docs and examples on how to use the Geocoder.

Comment: Btw. use and watch your javascript console. A simple `console.log(locations)` before your `for` loop should have explained a lot.

Comment: @MrUpsidown thank you very much for your answer. It has been key to work on and now I have it working. Also, thank you for the advice about billing, I was aware of that but I'm working on development stage and I wasn't concerned about it yet.